# Comparing "old" and "new" hibernate object for logging does not work correctly for collections

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I use Spring Boot, JPA (Hibernate) and MySQL db. In the entity save method there is logic for logging (entity added or changed), for this I use the following code:

```
public Entity save(Entity entity) {

        Entity oldEntity = findOldEntity(entity);

        Entity newEntity = repository.save(entity);
        ofNullable(oldEntity)
                .ifPresentOrElse(oldValue -> logService.edit(oldValue, newEntity),
                        () -> logService.add(newEntity));
        return newEntity;
    }
```

An entity with new fields is passed to the method, then an existing object is retrieved from the database by identifier -> the new object is saved in the database -> it is checked if the old object exists, then a log is written about changing the object, if not, then a log about creating a new object.
The method that gets the existing (findOldEntity()) object from the database looks like this:

```
 @Transactional
    public <U> U findOldEntity(Class<U> classType, Long id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            U result = null;
            Session session = null;
            try {
                Session jpaSession = (Session)this.entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
                SessionFactory factory = jpaSession.getSessionFactory();
                session = factory.openSession();
                result = session.get(classType, id);
            } catch (Exception e) {
               // 
            } finally {
                if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
                    session.close();
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Entity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String value;

    @OneToMany
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<AnotherEntity> otherEntities = new ArrayList<>();
```

This works well for value field, but the entity also contains a one-to-many collection.
The problem is that when a new entity arrives where elements were added to the collection, the entity is retrieved from the database where there are no elements in the collection yet, then the new entity is saved and after that the old and new object become the same (old.equals(new) but oldEntity!=newEntity), where ofNullable(oldEntity) ....

If you execute the code line by line in debugging, then there is no problem, but if you set a breakpoint here: ofNullable(oldEntity) .... then it will be seen that the old and new objects have identical fields (although at the beginning of the method the old object had an empty collection, and the saved object has one element in the collection). However, the objects themselves are different. That is, the speed with which the code is executed also affects

I added the **@Transactional** annotation to the save() method and everything works correctly, however, I want to know the reason for this behavior and how I can rewrite the code correctly so that changes in the old object are not overwritten by changes from the new object. I think it has something to do with **PersistenceContext**

Comment: Find returns a managed entity instance, and save, which calls merge under the covers, merges the entity you pass in overtop of the managed entity instance and returns it. So oldEntity == newEntity. You should use the oldEntity instance you find and compare it to the 'entity' you pass in for logging purposes; and you can manually change the oldEntity instance with entity data yourself without calling save; JPA will pick up any edits to oldEntity when the transaction commits